# Getting TypeError: UIAElementInfo object can be initialized with integer or IUIAutomationElement instance only

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am new to Pywinauto and getting below error

Anything missing

Pywinauto version: 0.6.8

Python version : 3.8.2

Platform and OS: windows 10

Short Example of Code to Demonstrate the Problem

from pywinauto.application import Application

import time

import pyautogui

app=Application(backend='uia').start(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\blue8\client\App.exe")

time.sleep(5)

app=Application(backend='uia').connect(title='Main Window',timeout=10)

w1 = app.window(best_match='Main Window').wrapper_object()

w2 = app.window(handle=w1)

ctrl = w2['TreeView']

c1 = ctrl.get_item([u'xd Explorer', u'Annotation_AugCrime']).click_input(button="left", double=True)

c2 = c1.sub_elements()

getting below error at c1 line

TypeError: UIAElementInfo object can be initialized with integer or IUIAutomationElement instance only!